# Split a string in Java and picking up a part of it

Tags: java, split

Say I got a string from a text file like

"Yes ABC 123

Yes DEF 456

Yes GHI 789"

I use this code to split the string by whitespace.

```
while (inputFile.hasNext())
  {
     String stuff = inputFile.nextLine();

     String[] tokens = stuff.split(" ");

     for (String s : tokens)
     System.out.println(s);
  }
```

But I also want to assign Yes to a boolean, ABC to another string, 123 to a int.
How can I pick them up separately? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
boolean b=tokens[0].equalsIgnoreCase("yes");
String name=tokens[1];
int i=Integer.parseInt(tokens[2]);
```

Comment: Thank you. But how does parseInt work? I am a beginner and I don't know how to use that

Comment: `parseInt(<<number as string>>)` method accepts a string which is a number actually, and convert it to the int data type, but beware of exception when the string data(input data) is not in form of a number(like 190an).

Comment: nice. I didn't know that. Thank you for the heads up

Comment: @JeremyZhang Have a nice Java application dude :)

Answer (score 0):

Could you clarify what the exact purpose of what you're doing is? You can refer to the separate Strings with tokens[i] with i being the index. You could throw these into a switch statement (since Java 7) and match for the words you're looking for. Then you can take further action, i.e. convert the Strings to Booleans or Ints.

You should consider checking the input to be valid too even if you are expecting the file to always have those 3 words separated by a space.

Comment: Nothing. I am just trying to understand how to solve problems like this. Switch is a good idea. I will try it see how it works. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Create Class `Line` and `List<Line>` that will store all your file into list:

```
public class Line{

private boolean mFlag = false;
private int  mNum = 0;
private String  mStr;

public Line(String stuff) {
    String[] tokens = stuff.split("[ ]+");

    if(tokens.length ==3){
        mFlag=tokens[0].equalsIgnoreCase("yes");
        mNum=Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]);
        mStr=tokens[3];
    }
}
}
```

and call it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

 List<Line> list = new ArrayList<Line>(); 
 Line line;

 while (inputFile.hasNext())
 {
  String stuff = inputFile.nextLine();

  line = new Line(stuff);

  list.add(line);
 }
}
```

Comment: OMG......There are so much stuff I don't know in this code. Maybe I will try something I can currently understand. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Just for the future, by this way you can store you file to list of Objects where each Object contains `boolean`, `String`, `int`

Answer (score 0):

If your input String is going to be in the same format always i.e. `boolean`,`String` ,`int` then you can access the individual indices of `token` array and convert them to your specified format

```
boolean opinion = tokens[0].equalsIgnoreCase("yes");
String temp = token[1];
int i = Integer.parseInt(token[2])
```

But you might require to create an array or something that stores the values for consecutive inputs that user does otherwise these variables would be over ridden for every new input from user.

Comment: Thank you. But if I have 3 or more than 3 lines. That is to say I got 9 parts or more. How can I make the index if I don't know exactly how many parts are there?

Comment: After each line you `split` input into 3 parts and fill up three `ArrayList`(Just an exmaple you can use any knid of list you want) with these values and continue doing so till the user input the stop criteria. You can specify the stop criteria yourself like user just presses enter without any input.

Comment: Thank you. I see what's wrong with my thought. With the while (inputFile.hasNext()) loop, every time I will only get 3 parts. By the way Integer.ParseInt should be Integer.parseInt. Low case p.